# How to get calendar from date

Tags: java

I have some date and I want to get last x day before this date so this is my code:

```
            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            today.add(Calendar.DATE, -x);
            date = new Date(today.getTimeInMillis()))
```

this code works only if some day is actual day. How I can change it. Is there some method to get calendar from date ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [setTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime(java.util.Date)) method to set the date of your calendar :

```
Calendar aDay = Calendar.getInstance();
aDay.setTime(aDate);
```